# Update a QDockWidget's subwidgets which already happens naturally upon hovering over with mouse

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdockwidget

I have a QDockWidget in a QMainWindow, the QDockWidget contains a stack of QUndoViews containing commands that I want to change the text of in the QUndoView.  You accomplish this by doing command.setText().  However, the QUndoView is only showing the updated text when I hover over it with the mouse.  Not even will calling the below right after setText work:

```
    self.editor().undoView().setFocus()
    self.editor().undoView().update()
    self.editor().undoView().hide()
    self.editor().undoView().show()
```

Here is the minimal code to demonstrate the problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QDockWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, \
                             QStackedWidget, QUndoStack, QUndoCommand, QApplication, \
                             QUndoView)
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, Qt

class Command(QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def undo(self):
        print("Command Undone")

    def redo(self):
        print("Command Redone")


class CommandTimeline(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stackedWidget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setWidget(self.stackedWidget)

    def addUndoView(self, stack):
        view = QUndoView(stack)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(view)
        return view


class Obj(QObject):
    nameChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = name

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self.nameChanged.emit(name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._name


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.undoStack = QUndoStack()
        self.commandTimeline = CommandTimeline()
        self.commandTimeline.addUndoView(self.undoStack)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.commandTimeline)
        button = QPushButton("Click")
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(self.changeObjName)
        self.obj = Obj("A")
        self.addCommand()

    def addCommand(self):
        def getText(obj):
            return "The command text: " + str(obj)
        command = Command()
        command.setText(getText(self.obj))
        self.obj.nameChanged.connect(lambda name: command.setText(getText(self.obj)))
        self.undoStack.push(command)

    def changeObjName(self):
        self.obj.setName("B")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Run this code and notice that after clicking the button, the text in the undoview doesn't change, but after hovering over the dockwidget, the text updates immediately.

How can I trigger the update upon `command.setText()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QUndoCommand` does not notify if the text is changed, it is designed to have a static text. So we must do that task, in this case use `setFocus()`, you signal that it does not work, but for me it works so you probably have not implemented it correctly or your MCVE is not verifiable.

```
import sys

from functools import partial

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QDockWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, \
                             QStackedWidget, QUndoStack, QUndoCommand, QApplication, \
                             QUndoView)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, Qt

class Command(QUndoCommand):
    def undo(self):
        print("Command Undone")

    def redo(self):
        print("Command Redone")


class CommandTimeline(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stackedWidget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setWidget(self.stackedWidget)

    def addUndoView(self, stack):
        view = QUndoView(stack)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(view)
        return view


class Obj(QObject):
    nameChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = name

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self.nameChanged.emit(name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._name


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.undoStack = QUndoStack()
        self.commandTimeline = CommandTimeline()
        self.view = self.commandTimeline.addUndoView(self.undoStack)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.commandTimeline)
        button = QPushButton("Click")
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(self.changeObjName)
        self.obj = Obj("A")
        self.addCommand()


    def addCommand(self):
        command = Command()
        command.setText("The command text: {}".format(self.obj))
        self.obj.nameChanged.connect(partial(self.onNameChanged, command))
        self.undoStack.push(command)

    def changeObjName(self):
        self.obj.setName("B")

    def onNameChanged(self, command, name):
        fw = QApplication.focusWidget()
        command.setText("The command text: {}".format(name))
        self.view.setFocus()
        fw.setFocus()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Thank you!  Now you can see the text update instantaneously.